# Object find() can't be used on arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

How to find selected data? I have this `selectize`

[image]

and when I try `selectize.find("#state")` it return me empty. And it only works `selectize[1]`

but what if I have many select cause it's dynamic, i can't make it static like `selectize[4]`, how to find specified?

Comment: `.find` is not the right method for your problem. Did you read the documentation before you tried it? The documentation clearly states what it does.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a look at the documentation, you will read this about [`.find`](https://api.jquery.com/find/):

> Get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.

That's not what you want. You are *not* looking for a **descendant** with that ID, you are looking for an element with that ID among the selected elements themselves! That's what [**`.filter`**](https://api.jquery.com/filter/) is for: `.filter('#state')`.

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
object.querySelect("#state");
```

or

`.filter`

Comment: hi,is `querySelector`,sorry! `querySelector`  is ES6 method!

Comment: `querySelector` is a DOM method and as such has nothing to do with ES6 either.